# Is there any SWIFT message with multiple fields with same tag?

Tags: finance

I'm studing the SWIFT MT format to implement a Golang parser.
From the specs, Standards MT November 2022 - General Information, I found this message on the page #47:

[image: A field may appear only once in a sequence, unless repetition is specifically allowed.]

I suspect that there may have a certain MT message having multiple fields with the same tag ID.

So can anybody point it out just as an example.

Thank you.

Browsing this [Index of Messages](https://www.iso20022.org/15022/uhb) but there are hundreds of them to check one by one.

Answer (score 0):

well, I just found in the same specs file, on the page #13,

[image: repetitive fields]

So a field may appear multiple times in an MT message.

Regards